# Problem in the strange result of subtracting two float value in java

Tags: java, android

I've done the following subtraction:

```
float result = 0.53f - 0.5293873f;
```

But the result of subtraction is wrong, I expect the result to be 
**0.0006127** but result is **6.1267614E-4**

This question may be a duplicate, but I did not find the answer after very search.

I want to know what is the cause of this problem and what is the solution

Thanks.

Comment: The scientific notation for 0.00061267614. As `float` has a precision of 7-8 digits the approximation error is to be expected.

Comment: Thanks Joop Eggen, but what is solution?

Comment: `new BigDecimal("0.53").substract("0.5293873").toPlainString()` = exact precision and no scientific notation.

Comment: Thanks, I've also read where this error only occurs when printing and the result value is correct and can be used

Comment: No, every floating point (float, double) is a sum of powers of 2. So 0.25 is precise, but 0.1 which would be an infinite sum of (negative) powers of 2 is just an approximation. But on printing one could the number a bit repaired. Use double/float for scalable graphics and BigDecimal for financial purposes.

Comment: Thank you mr Joop Eggen